# Instantiating a prefab and adding it to a RectTransform sets abnormal values to its local scale

Tags: unity-game-engine

If you instantiate a prefab and parent it to an object under a UI Canvas or any RectTransform really, its scale would have "abnormal" values, in my case, they were equal to the reference Pixels Per Unit value. Why? Is this a bug or is this behavior by design?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was having issue parenting UI items, then I started using:

```
 rectTransform.SetParent(parentTransform, false);
```

and it solved it. Notice the second parameter, it indicates you do not wish the transform values to be in world space but in local space of the parent instead.

That could be it for you too.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Let me check this one out and give you my feedback.